# How to pass const array of strings back from c dll to c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, dll, pinvoke

I have C# code that calls a C dll.  The dll has the following global const array of strings:

```
const char *PtxEditorColumnHeaders[] = {
    "Ptx#",
    "Primitive",
    "PtxType",
    "_END_COLUMNS"
};
```

All I want to do is grab this text and stuff it into the Column text of a ListView control.
I have found there are several ways to do this, using Pinvoke, strcpy, etc.  But, since I'm still learning c# and so far uncorrupted in my ways, what is the best practices way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write a C function to return the pointer to the first element of the array, and the number of elements:

```
const char **GetPtxEditorColumnHeaders(int *count)
{
    *count = 4;//or however you want to get hold of this information
    return PtxEditorColumnHeaders;
}
```

And then declare the p/invoke:

```
[DllImport(@"mydll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr GetPtxEditorColumnHeaders(out int count);
```

Call the function like this:

```
int count;
IntPtr PtxEditorColumnHeaders = GetPtxEditorColumnHeaders(out count);
List<string> headers = new List<string>();
for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    IntPtr strPtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(PtxEditorColumnHeaders);
    headers.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(strPtr));
    PtxEditorColumnHeaders += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));
}
```

This stuff gets tedious pretty quickly, at which point a C++/CLI wrapper begins to look like a more attractive option.

Comment: Can you point me to a ref where there are some examples of a wrapper for C code?  Everything I see talks about Pinvoke...

Comment: A quick websearch yielded this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppCLINativeDllWrapper-29c32acd